# Where is actually documented, that "\e" stands for the Alt key in .inputrc

Tags: bash, inputrc

A few days ago I learned, that I can use

```
"\ej": history-search-backward
"\ek": history-search-forward
```

for avoiding the arrow keys. Now while that works like a charm and i began to read the bash-docs to learn more about .inputrc.
Please have a look at this page ( especially the part about keybindings.)
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax
 \e is mentioned as "an escape character". While english is not my first language I would never assume this could be used to map Alt. That's an ongoing scheme with me and documentation. They somewhat feel more examplatory than explanatory to me.
The question is: Where is that stuff actually written down, so that others could have know about and give the Tip in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mapping of the `Alt` key to `Escape` (ASCII 033, `"\e"`) is done by your terminal emulator, the readline library (which handles the `~/.inputrc`) has no part in it.

The problem is that there is no way to send the actual key events to a program running in a terminal; the terminal will convert them into sequences of bytes which the program can read from the tty.

For the Alt/Meta key, there are two ways to do it:

1. Map it to Escape (ASCII 033 / 0x1b) -- pressing `Alt-K` will actually send `"\ek"`, `Alt-Shift-K` `"\eK"`, etc. This is the default in most terminal emulators, but it's usually configurable and you have all the reasons to make it the default if it already isn't.
2. Turn on the high 7th bit on the ASCII value of the key -- pressing `Alt-K` will actually send the `0x6b | 0x80 = 0xeb` byte, `0x6b` being the ASCII value of `"k"`.

It's the latter which is recognized as `"\M-k"` in readline bindings.

And that does **not** work and is horribly broken with any multibyte locales like `en_US.UTF-8` (which are the default on most modern systems). On such system, the terminal emulator may not send the raw `0xeb` byte (which is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, but binary garbage), but may convert it from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, resulting in the `"\xc3\xab" = "ë"` (`e` with diaeresis) being sent when `Alt-K` is pressed.

But readline doesn't know how to map `"ë"` back to `"\M-k"` no matter how much you fiddle with the plethora of options like `convert-meta`, `enable-meta-key`, `input-meta`, etc.

And even if you could do it, that would still be broken, because people may actually want to type `"ë"` and `"ó"` and will not appreciate those being handled as unrelated keys like `Alt-K` and `Alt-S`.

Answer (score 3):

You should find that `\e` is *the* escape character (meaning there's only one of them, character code 27, often written `ESC`) rather than *an* escape character (meaning one of several).

I think in this instance the documentation is trying to say that `\e` represents an instance of the ESC character, so that one could write `\e\e` for two ESC characters.

It does not represent ALT.

Comment: Well, ok, that's exactly what I would have expected when I read it. The funny thing now is the to mappings I stated in the question are actually matching Alt-k and Alt-j.

Comment: These keybindings should also work with Escape key instead of Alt.

Comment: No they don't. As I said, that's the weird part of docs sometimes they seem to be just plain wrong.

Comment: @chalybeum: Did you try? In readline programs, ESC followed by a key is usually equivalent to ALT+key. (e.g. in bash: ALT+. repeats the last parameter from the last command; ESC followed by . does the same thing.)

Comment: @chalybeum: yes, they do. Read up on [Meta key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key) and read `Readline Notation` part in `man bash`.

Comment: Ok, forgive me. I had to reload the config. Now \e indeed works for Alt and the escape key. According to the Readline Notation I also tried to use the M-j notation, but that doesn't do anything. By the way, the link in the question is the same text as man bash.